# Creating a View feed: Do not summarize, but show whole post

Tags: views, 6, feeds

I've created a feed in a view, and it seems to automatically summarize the info. I'd like the entire post to be available.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the sounds of it your view will be set to display teasers.

on your view edit page, under format, you have show, if set to "content | teaser" it is only displaying the teaser to display the full node click on teaser and then set the view mode to full content.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a format option. (I'm using D6)

Comment: Aw, found it Row Style > (Click on settings wheel icon) > Display Text > Full Text

Comment: yes my instructions were based on drupal 7's views module, at least you have found it now